# Databricks spark best practice for writing a structured stream to a lot of sinks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using databricks spark 3.x, and I am reading a very large number of streams (100+), and each stream has its own contract, and needs to be written out to its own delta/parquet/sql/whatever table. While this is a lot of streams, the activity per stream is low - some streams might see only hundreds of records a day. I do want to stream because I am aiming for a fairly low-latency approach.

Here's what I'm talking about (code abbreviated for simplicity; I'm using checkpoints, output modes, etc. correctly).
Assume a `schemas` variable contains the schema for each topic. I've tried this approach, where I create a ton of individual streams, but it takes a lot of compute and most of it is wasted:

```
def batchprocessor(topic, schema):
  def F(df, batchId):
    sql = f'''
  MERGE INTO SOME TABLE
  USING SOME MERGE TABLE ON SOME CONDITION
  WHEN MATCHED
  UPDATE SET *
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  INSERT *
  '''
    df.createOrReplaceTempView(f"SOME MERGE TABLE")
    df._jdf.sparkSession().sql(sql)
  return F
for topic in topics:
  query = (spark
    .readStream
    .format("delta")
    .load(f"/my-stream-one-table-per-topic/{topic}")
    .withColumn('json', from_json(col('value'),schemas[topic]))
    .select(col('json.*'))
    .writeStream
    .format("delta")
    .foreachBatch(batchProcessor(topic, schema))
    .start())
```

I also tried to create just one stream that did a ton of filtering, but performance was pretty abysmal even in a test environment where I pushed a single message to a single topic:

```
def batchprocessor(df, batchId):
  df.cache()
  for topic in topics:
    filteredDf = (df.filter(f"topic == '{topic}'")
      .withColumn('json', from_json(col('value'),schemas[topic]))
      .select(col('json.*')))
    sql = f'''
  MERGE INTO SOME TABLE
  USING SOME MERGE TABLE ON SOME CONDITION
  WHEN MATCHED
  UPDATE SET *
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  INSERT *
  '''
    filteredDf.createOrReplaceTempView(f"SOME MERGE TABLE")
    filteredDf._jdf.sparkSession().sql(sql)
  df.unpersist()

query = (spark
.readStream
.format("delta")
.load(f"/my-stream-all-topics-in-one-but-partitioned")
.writeStream
.format("delta")
.foreachBatch(batchProcessor)
.start())
```

Is there any good way to essentially demultiplex a stream like this? It's already partitioned, so I assume the query planner isn't doing too much redundant work, but it seems like there's a huge amount of overhead nonetheless.

Comment: what is the touchpoint to Kafka? I see you are reading and writing to delta lake...

Comment: I'm doing a two-stage process where I stream from kafka (119 topics), write to delta lake, then stream from delta lake (bronze/silver/gold architecture). I've tried writing all the topics to one partitioned table, and writing each topic to its own table, because those have different effects on this phase of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I ran a bunch of benchmarks, and option 2 is more efficient. I don't entirely know why yet.

Ultimately, performance still wasn't what I wanted - each topic runs in order, no matter the size, so a single record on each topic would lead the FIFO scheduler to queue up a lot of very inefficient small operations. I solved that using parallelisation:

```
import threading
def writeTable(table, df, poolId, sc):
  sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", poolId)
  df.write.mode('append').format('delta').saveAsTable(table)
  sc.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", None)
def processBatch(df, batchId):
  df.cache()
  dfsToWrite = {}
  for row in df.select('table').distinct().collect():
    table = row.table
    filteredDf = df.filter(f"table = '{table}'")
    dfsToWrite[table] = filteredDf
  threads = []
  for table,df in dfsToWrite.items():
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=writeTable,args=(table, df,table,spark.sparkContext)))
  for t in threads:
    t.start()
  for t in threads:
    t.join()
  df.unpersist()
```

Comment: What was the final solution you went for? I believe the second solution might be faster because you’re not reading data from Kafka multiple times. I have an identical problem and I’m really disappointed with the performance. It seems that having many slow streams is a big overhead for Spark.

Comment: I think the reason for the difference was the amount of overhead the driver does for each streaming query - having only one streaming query minimizes this. I wasn't totally satisfied with my second approach, though, because each topic occupies the FIFO scheduler entirely until it's complete, so a nightmare scenario where each topic has exactly one message produces a linear series of very inefficient writes. I ultimately got the performance I needed by using python threads and spark pools to get true parallelization within the foreachbatch. I updated my answer with sample code

Comment: Thanks for responding, when I wrote my first comment I felt like: https://xkcd.com/979/ 

Anyway, I noticed that in your solution you no longer use "MERGE INTO TABLE..." - was it impacting negatively performance for you as well? Downside is you might end up with duplicates.

How many different pools are you using? Is it 1 per topic? 

I tried tuning spark by manipulating SPARK_WORKER_CORES value to get more concurrency per core and used threading in Scala but I'm unimpressed with the latency and how much CPU this consumes.

Comment: This solution does hit cpu pretty hard, but in my case (130+ topics, only 4-5 see high use) it dropped latency from ~7 minutes to ~20 seconds. I'm using one pool per topic. I ditched merge into table for unrelated reasons, sorry - I was just looking for every optimization I could find and determined that the "if matched" branch was never being hit.